# How to ignore or exclude a folder during a gulp task. (I need the syntax)

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to ignore one or multiple folders with something like this (saw this on a forum),

```
return gulp.src([config.html + '**/*.php','!assets','!myPhpTestFolder', '!build', '!html'])
```

...assets, myPhpTestFolder, build, html ...are the folders in the root i would like to exclude/ignore during the minify task.
But it doesn't work.  It still minifies everything in the root folder with a .php on the file.  Thanks for any help.  Jason

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator means something like "exclude what is matched by the glob that follows". A glob like `assets` matches only the file named `assets`. If it is a directory, it will match the directory of that name, not the directory *and* the files inside it. If you wanted to match the directory, and the files in it, then you'd have to give `assets/**/*`. So when you want to negate the directory and the files in it, you have to negate `assets/**/*`.

So the final glob should be `!assets/**/*`. Same for the other directories: negate a glob that matches all descendants of the directory.